# How to integrate function with divisors?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions

I need to integrate the following function:

$$\int (4x^2 +3x+7+\, \frac5{3x} -\frac3{x^2})dx$$

I'm trying to do it term by term by using the exponent rule:

$$\int x^ndx = \frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}$$

So I get:

$$\int4x^2dx = \frac43x^3+C$$

$$\int3xdx = \frac32x^2+C$$
$$\int7dx = 7x + C$$

But I have no idea as how I should integrate the last two terms with divisors. Could I have some advise?

Comment: For $\int \frac{5}{3}x=\frac{5\ln(x)}{3}$, because $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: If your homework asks this, you are supposed to know from your course that $\int x^\alpha dx=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+C$ for all real $\alpha\ne-1$ and $\int\frac1x dx=\log|x|+C$.

Comment: But what if numerator is not $1$ like in this case with $\frac5{3x}$? Does the logarithm rule still apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat $$-\frac{3}{x^2}$$As: $$-3\cdot x^{-2}$$So the $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ rule works fine: $$-\frac{3}{(-2)+1)}x^{(-2)+1}=3\cdot x^{-1}=\frac{3}{x}$$Is your desired integral. $1/x$ is a bit tricky as $n=-1$, so $\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{0}$. This rule *doesn't work* here, also because $\frac{d}{dx}x^0=0$ not $x^{-1}$. We have a new ""rule"" for this case: $$\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\ln t$$Where appears the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). You can treat this as a definition of $\ln$, or as a corollary of other definitions - your choice. Either way, it is the antiderivative of $1/x$ (for $x\gt0$ - if $x\lt 0$ you need to deal with $\ln|x|$)

Comment: Alright, what about converting $$\frac5{3x}$$? Would that be $$5*3x^-1$$?

Comment: Nevermind, I finally understood your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Once you accept $\ln$ it works the same - $\int\frac{5}{3x}=\frac{5}{3}\ln|x|$ since $5/3$ is a constant @Mr.Engineer